# What's an offset?

Tags: assembly, mips, offset

I keep seeing the offset word in MIPS instruction tables like [this one](http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html):

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|                           BEQ                                |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| Description:                                                 |
|                                                              |
| Branches if the two registers are equal                      |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| Operation:                                                   |
|                                                              |
| if $s == $t advance_pc (offset << 2)); else advance_pc (4);  |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| Syntax:                                                      |
|                                                              |
| beq $s, $t, offset                                           |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| Encoding:                                                    |
|                                                              |
| 0001 00ss ssst tttt iiii iiii iiii iiii                      |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

What's an offset exacly?

Comment: [Offset (computer science)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offset_%28computer_science%29). Basically, it's a delta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Offset, in terms of topology is the moving vector in an ordered set. Offset is definable if and only if there is a starting element, compared to which you define the move. Let's suppose you have the geometric point of

(x1, ..., xn)

If you need to focus a move from this point, then the offset vector can be defined as

(o1, ..., on)

and the result point is:

(x1 + o1, ..., xn + on)

If you have an ordered list, then a numeric offset of o tells you the index you should work on.

> In computer science, an offset within an array or other data structure
>   object is an integer indicating the distance (displacement) from the
>   beginning of the object up until a given element or point, presumably
>   within the same object. The concept of a distance is valid only if all
>   elements of the object are of the same size (typically given in bytes
>   or words).

Taken from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offset_%28computer_science%29). However, the quote is slightly inaccurate, since distance does not require to have equal-sized objects, the dependency is the presence of metric spaces. Also, the quote tells you that you have to have a smallest element in your algebraic structure, which is not exactly a dependency. More generally, you need to have a well-defined starting point.

In your particular case, offset is a numeric value, measured in bytes, which represents the moving vector from a certain location in memory. Note, that 32 bits are four bytes, this is why you have an offset of 4.

Answer (score 0):

And a less-mathematical explanation: the branch is relative to program counter. The offset says how "far" from "current" PC value (offset to add to PC to get to the destination). In assembly the offset is usually calculated by the assembler, so you just put a destination there